# Potentiometer circle button

Tags: java, android, xml, button, view

I have to make a volume button.

The button have to be used like in real life : Means that the user **drag it in circle**

The thing is i have **no idea how to do it**.

I already got through google and **the only thing i found was how to do a circular seekbar**, which is not good since i have only one image/button

How can i acheive that ?

[image: the button]

[image: behind the button]

**EDIT 1 :**

For now i found this :

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Cartesian_coordinates_2D.svg

Comment: You probably need to create a custom component for something like that. Check out [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) guide for some guidance.

Comment: should i extend directly View or should i do a Compound View if i want the background image and the button image in the same View (the two images i posted)  ? This is new for me

Comment: See the edit ofr more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to create your [own custom View](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) 
But if you don't want to do this.

Then just use this [**SeekArc around**](https://github.com/TriggerTrap/SeekArc) your image and [customize its thumb and color](https://www.google.com.pk/search?newwindow=1&q=custom%20seekbar%20android%20example%20stackoverflow&spell=1&sa=X&ei=jEiqVOyiIsOyuASTq4LgDA&ved=0CBkQvwUoAA&biw=1280&bih=620) to look like your view and change volume as you want.

if you need any assistant,ask me

[**Custom Rotatory knob**](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/11/custom-rotary-knob-control-for-android/#.VKpuwZSSy9o)

Comment: i found a solution already. I created a custom view as you said

Comment: So why don't you share your answer to other, if it is going to be O.K with you

Comment: srry i don't have the sources anymore (i changed company) that's why i accepted your answer. But i used the links from my edit1 and created a custom view from it